# Joomla path and URL for subdir installation

Tags: joomla

Does anyone know how can I get the path and URL of the Joomla installation relative to the document root and site domain? I am looking for the Wordpress correspondent of WP_CONTENT_DIR and WP_CONTENT_URL.

Thanks all,
Bogdan

I managed to find that part of the URL using this piece of code: `$installation_dir_in_url = substr(str_replace(DS, '/', JPATH_SITE), strlen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you need:

```
 JURI::base()
```

Also check this Joomla documentations out http://docs.joomla.org/JURI

Comment: Actually I was looking for `JURI::root(true)`, but your answer did help a lot.

Comment: Cool, well glad to be of help.